# C# Verify Code for playing 2 audio tracks at specific SNR

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I have two WAV audio tracks which I want to play at SNR of +10, +8,+6,+4 and 0db respectively

Formula of SNR (db) = 20 log(rms of signal / rms of noise)

For this purpose, I need to calculate and set the SNR of my audio tracks using the language C#. I finally came up with this solution thanks to people and want to verify it.

Here is what I did:

```
    public void play(int required_snr)
    {
        WaveFileReader signal = new WaveFileReader(@"E:\signal.wav"),
                            noise = new WaveFileReader(@"E:\noise.wav");

        int signal_length = (int)signal.Length, noise_length = (int)noise.Length, i;

        byte[] signal_sample = new byte[signal_length], noise_sample = new byte[noise_length];

        int signal_read = signal.Read(signal_sample, 0, signal_length) / 2, noise_read = noise.Read(noise_sample, 0, noise_length) / 2;

        float[] sample_arr = new float[signal_read], noise_arr = new float[noise_read];
        float sum = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < sample_arr.Length; i++)
        {
            sample_arr[i] = (float)BitConverter.ToInt16(signal_sample, i * 2) / 32768f;
            sum += (sample_arr[i] * sample_arr[i]);
        }

        float rms_signal = (float)Math.Sqrt((sum / sample_arr.Length));

        sum = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < noise_arr.Length; i++)
        {
            noise_arr[i] = (float)BitConverter.ToInt16(noise_sample, i * 2) / 32768f;
            sum += (noise_arr[i] * noise_arr[i]);
        }

        float rms_noise = (float)Math.Sqrt((sum / noise_arr.Length));

        float snr_db = (float)Math.Round(20 * Math.Log10(rms_signal / rms_noise), 1);

        float factor = (float)Math.Pow(10, (required_snr - snr_db) / 20);

        rms_noise = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < noise_arr.Length; i++)
        {
            noise_arr[i] = noise_arr[i] / factor;

            rms_noise += (noise_arr[i] * noise_arr[i]);
        }

        rms_noise = (float)Math.Sqrt((rms_noise / noise_arr.Length));
        snr_db = (float)Math.Round(20 * Math.Log10(rms_signal / rms_noise), 1);

        using (WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(@"E:\aw4.wav", noise.WaveFormat))
        {
            for (i = 0; i < noise_arr.Length; i++)
                writer.WriteSample(noise_arr[i]);
        }

        WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(@"E:\aw4.wav");
        WaveOut waveOut = new WaveOut();
        waveOut.Init(reader);
        waveOut.Play();

        WaveFileReader si = new WaveFileReader(@"E:\signal.wav");
        WaveOut o = new WaveOut();
        o.Init(si);
        o.Play();
    }
```

Is this code correct?
I am a noob in DSP so I dont know.
But I do hear and feel the changes in the noise volume level which increases as I decrease my required SNR from 10 to 0.

Comment: Rather than voting down, can you tell me the solution please?

Comment: I want to set the SNR..the link you posted isn't related

Comment: you miss a `noise_rms = 0`before the second loop.

Comment: Thank you, but this didnt change anything.... :(

Comment: The cast in `(byte)(noise_samples[i] / factor);`is bogus. samples are **not** bytes. BTW: what is the format fo your WAV file (sample size, sampling rate, number of channels, etc)?

Comment: i did the type casting because the LHS is a byte array..NAudio's read method requires byte array..

Comment: Urmm..sampling rate is normal 44100 Hz...it's 16 but PCM, 48kHz 2 channels...this is what noise.WaveFormat printed..

Comment: 16 Bit PCM, 2 Channels, so you need a short[][] array for the two 16 Bit channels in one signal.

Comment: What does this mean?

Comment: Where do I make the changes?

Comment: It's not two...it's one..actually some are 2 channels and some are 1..

Comment: I think here is the next step for you: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/digital-audio-fundamentals

Comment: :(
Okay , I'm sorry.

Comment: Please see the code now @DrKoch

Comment: Nice so far. What are the outputs? I resulting SNR correct? Now you need to find a way to convert your float[] back to short samples. Try this for each sample: int16 s = (int16)(f * 32786); then BitConverter.GetBytes()

Comment: Resulting SNR is correct..you mean this way: for (i = 0; i < noise_arr.Length; i++ )
            {
                Int16 s = (Int16)(noise_arr[i] * 32786);
                noise_sample = BitConverter.GetBytes(s);
            }

Comment: @DrKoch, No my method is incorrect..BitConverter.GetBytes() takes a single sample as input but returns a byte array..

Comment: turns out no conversion was required...Thanks to @MarkHeath NAudio has a method called WriteSample which takes a float value as input...so I just did:  using (WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(@"E:\aw4.wav", noise.WaveFormat))
            {
                for (i = 0; i < noise_arr.Length; i++)
                    writer.WriteSample(noise_arr[i]);
            }

Comment: Hi @DrKoch, please go through my code once and tell if everything is correct. And YES I do feel the difference when the required SNR decreases, but I want to be 100% sure that the code is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to produce an audio signal with a defined signal-to-noise ratio (SNR). This implies that you have **two** audio signals, one is *signal* the other is *noise*.

All the following can be done by direct sample (int) manipulation, multiplying a sample with a factor or adding two samples.

First you have to measure the RMS (root mean square) Level of both signals. This is (as the name implies) Thre root of the mean of all squared samples, expressed as a decibel value:

```
 db = 20*Log10(amplitude)
```

Assuming you have a signal with 30 dB and a noise with 20 dB you will arrive at a SNR of 30-20 = 10dB.

If you need a better SNR you have to either amplify the signal or weaken the noise.

You amplify by multiplicating all samples with a constant factor. (Be careful to not overload, i.e. produce samples too large for the allowed integer range)

```
factor = exp10(db/20);
```

Finally you add both signals to arrive at the combined signal with the wanted SNR.

---

**Edit**

The signal to noise ratio can be calculated in two ways:

```
snr1 = 20 * log10(rms_signal / rms_noise)
```

or using log (decibel) values:

```
snr2 = db_signal - db_noise
```

These two are equivalent.

Here the more detailed steps to produce a mixed signal with a defined SNR from two audio tracks.

**Method1 linear calculation**

Calculate the linear rms of both signals:

```
rms := sqrt ( sum(x*x) / num(x) )
```

With x are all the samples (usually int16) of an audio track.

A SNR of 6 dB is equivalent to a linear ratio of exp10(6/20) = 2.0

So if you found an average amplitude (rms) of `160` for both of your signal, you'll have either to multiply *signal* by two or divide *noise* by two. This will result in two rms values of 160 and 80 which gives you the expected SNR of 2.0 (linear) or 6.0 dB.

**Method2 logarithmic calculation**

First calculate linear rms as above (results in signal = 160, noise = 160)

Second calc decibel of this rms values, results in signal=40 dB noise = 40dB

So the current SNR is 40-40 = 0dB, both parts have the same power.

To arrive at an SNR of 6dB you'll have to lower the noise component by 6dB.

The factor needed to do so is exp10(6.0/20.0) = 2.0

So you have to divide your noise signal by 2.0.

This will give you a linear rms of 80 for the noise signal.

So finally you have a SNR = 20.0 * log10(160/80) = 6.0

---

**Edit**

After modifying the noise signal, you have to mix signal and noise:

```
for(...)  mix[i] = signal[i] + noise[i];
```

This will result in a noisy signal with the required SNR.

Comment: here in the factor = exp10(db/20) formula, db is my required db ?

Comment: if you find an snr of 10dB and want one of 6dB then you have to modify one of your signals by 4dB. Then db=4 for this formula

Comment: I have the following code which gets the rms and rms db:

            WaveFileReader readertest = new WaveFileReader(@"E:\MARK\Audio Tracks\Volume.wav");

                int bytesnumber = (int)readertest.Length;

                byte[] buf = new byte[bytesnumber];

                readertest.Read(buf, 0, bytesnumber);

                double sum = 0;

                foreach (int i in buf)
                    sum += i * i;

                double mean = sum / (buf.Length*1.0);

                double rms = Math.Sqrt(mean);

                double rmsdb = 20 * Math.Log10(rms);

Comment: Looks good. Watch out for overflows in sum (sum gets so large, that sum+i doesn't make any difference any more). Do you get reasonable results?

Comment: I'm not sure about the rms in db part..will it be 20*math.log10(rms) ?

You had written 20*Mat.log10(amplitude)

Comment: well, the rms is excactly that: an averaged amplitude.

Comment: So I get the RMS in DB of the 2 audios, now next what ?

Comment: see second part of my answer.

Comment: When i print the value of my rmsdb variable it gave 43.9526. Is this the SNR value of my audio?

Comment: No. This is the RMS of one signal. You need the RMS of the second signal to calculate signal-to-noise ratio: snr = db1 - db2

Comment: (1) I founded RMS db same way as above for both signal and noise. I got signal as 44.0685 which I rounded of to 44 and noise as 44.145 which i also rounded of to 44 (2) I subtracted them and got 0 as result and as i require 10db as snr so according to formula -> factor = exp10(db/20) i put numerator as 10 and (3) whatever result i got i multiplied that with all the samples of my signal

Comment: I got a negative snr of -0.07665 with one of my signals and noise

Comment: I am taking Ceiling of the solutions...that made -0.07665 = 0
Is this a major problem?

Comment: Negative SNR after db1 - db2: signal2 is louder. For all practical usages you should round dB values to one decimal place: 41.2 dB

Comment: Instead `buf2[i] /= 2`you need `buf[i] /= factor`

Comment: "So the current SNR is 40-40 = 0dB, both parts have the same power.

To arrive at an SNR of 6dB you'll have to lower the noise component by 6dB.

The factor needed to do so is exp10(6.0/20.0) = 2.0

So you have to divide your noise signal by 2.0."

I got 0 db snr upon executing the above code for 6db and thus I divided by 2 as u had suggested.

Comment: Hi, please look at the edited code which i posted. It gives a clearer picture of my problem

Comment: Please try to understand each step in my answer. Code it, check values, listen to the result. You still lack basic understanding af db calculation, scaling and mixing of audio signals. your calculation of snrdb is bogus (snr already being logarithmic) you still miss the calculation of factor and the mixing step.

Comment: Why do I need to calculate the factor if my initial SNR is 0 and my required is 6 ...this means i need to divide each sample by 2...
And instead of mixing cant i just play the two audios separately?

Comment: I am so so sorry..I misunderstood the 2.0 and 6db...
I am finding everything in linear scale..Therefore I need SNR as 2 and not 6 in my case..Since my initial SNR is 0, therefore I need to divide noise by 1.25 rounded off to 1 right?

Comment: From your question: You want a SNR of 6dB, this means signal is 6dB more/louder than noise, or in linear terms, lin_rms(signal) = 2* lin_rms(noise). A SNR is defined for a **combined** signal only, so you have to mix both components to get a "noisy" signal with the desired signal to noise ratio.

Comment: We can divide samples by a fraction like 3.2 , 3.4, 2.7 etc?
Or does it always have to be integers?

Comment: A _sample_ is typically a signed 16-Bit integer.

Comment: I did everything...it is giving the correct answer in theory but when I play the noise audio separately with decreasing order of required SNR from 10 to 8 to 6 to 4 to 0 it decreases the loudness of audio instead of increasing it...With respect to this noise , the volume of signal file remains constant hence becomes inaudible with each change from 0 to 4 to 6 to 8 to 10 instead of becoming more audible...I have edited my code too...

Comment: if you multiply with x > 1.0 it gets louder. If you multiply with x < 1.0 it gets weaker.

Comment: Probably you need `double diff = snr_db - required_SNR;`